# Слайдер страниц без backbone

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать слайдер страниц без `backbone`?
http://poselok-programmistov.ru/concept/  - вот тут выглядит очень неплохо, то есть контент меняется, и URL без перезагрузки и без шарпа (#).

Comment: а в чем собственно проблема ?

Comment: В том что я не знаю как реализовать подгрузку страниц без перезагрузки страницы с изменением url и что бы все это было гладко как на сайте примере) но без backbone

Comment: Буду очень признателен если поделитесь идеями))
В проекте использую twitter bootstrap(с jquery естественно)

Comment: Не знаю на счет `twitter`, но такое можно на [https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax](pjax) сделать.

Comment: pjax не заработал...Но jquery history (ajaxify) заработал,